# how to resize the dropdown submenu when the browser resizes

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
 padding: 13%;
}



#mimenu{
 
 padding-right: 15%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 background-color: white;
}

 a.nav-link.cuatro  {
 position: relative;
 left:-25%;
}


 a.nav-link.uno  {
 position: relative;
 left:-23%;
  text-align: center;
}

 a.nav-link.dos {
 position: relative;
 left:-53%;
  text-align: center;
}

a.nav-link.tres {
 position: relative;
 left:-20%;
 text-align: center;
}

a.nav-link.cinco {
 position: relative;
 left:-20%;
 text-align: center;
}


a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.dos{
 position: relative;
 left:-15%;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.Logo {
 
 
    width: 87%;
 position: relative;
 left:30%;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 
 
}


#uno{

padding: 0;


}


.nav-link.uno:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 
}


.nav-link.dos:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}

.nav-link.tres:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}


.nav-link.cuatro:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}

.nav-link.cinco:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}


.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
    color: white!important;
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(178,205,73,1.00)!important;
 
}

.dropdown-item{
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 width: 100%;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: rgb(0,171,235);
 
}

.dropdown-item:hover{
 
 color: rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 background: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item{
 position: relative;
 left:13%;
 

}

i.fa.fa-facebook{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-783%
  
}

i.fa.fa-facebook:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-783%
  
}



i.fa.fa-twitter{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-453%;
}

i.fa.fa-twitter:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-453%;
}




i.fa.fa-youtube{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-443%
}


i.fa.fa-youtube:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-443%
}

i.fa.fa-instagram{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-407%;
    bottom:-6%;
}

i.fa.fa-instagram:hover{
color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 
}

i.fa.fa-envelope{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-7%
}



i.fa.fa-envelope:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-7%
}



a.info{
    color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:23%
} 




a.info:hover{
    color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:23%
} 


a.tel{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 font-family: arial;
 text-decoration:none;
}


a.tel:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 font-family: arial;
 text-decoration:none;
}





a.info{
color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00); 
font-family: arial;
text-decoration:none; 
}



.dropdown-submenu{
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu a::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 40%;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:focus .dropdown-menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .dropdown-menu{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu{
        width: auto;
    }
}


.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: rgb(0,171,235);
 text-align-last: center; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-12 ">  
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="menusocial">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#" class="tel"> <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(4)7916510 ext(1501)</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="mailto:info@clinicacasadelnino.com" class="info"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@clinicacasadelnino.com</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" id="uno">
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="mimenu" >

<div class="col-md-3 encabezado" id="gradiente1">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/2jii6Eq.png" title="source: imgur.com" class="Logo">

</div>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mimenu2">
<li class="nav-item b ">
<a class="nav-link  dos " href="#">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item a dropdown">
<a class="nav-link uno dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Quienes Somos</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu"   aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Visión Misión y Objetivos Estrategicos</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reseña Historica</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Políticas Institucionales</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Valores</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dos" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Nuestros Servicios
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios Principales</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Urgencias</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">UCI Neonatal</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">UCI Adultos</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirugía</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hospitalización</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salas de parto</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios de apoyo</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicio de transfusión sanguínea</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Esterilización</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Imagenología</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicio farmacéutico</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nutrición</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Terapia física y respiratoria </a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ambulancia</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios de Consulta Externa</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicio de transfusión sanguínea</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pediatría</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ginecología y obstetricia</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirugía General</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirugía Pediátrica</a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item c">
<a class="nav-link tres" href="#">Responsabilidad Social</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item d">
<a class="nav-link  cuatro" href="#">Laboratorio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item d">
<a class="nav-link  cinco" href="#">Correo Corporativo</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row fila2">
<div class="col-12 imagenesc">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/GKeJMwS.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" alt="First slide"/>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block img-fluid"  alt="Second slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/CaZbz8L.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Nextborder</span> </a><!----fin carousel----->      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

hello i have some problem with my dropdown submenu i want to that menu be responsive, the other problem is my logo image , also i want the logo be responsive , i move the logo to the  left, but when i resize the browser the logo move next to the navbar button, also i want to fix my second navbar menu, is a social menu with social icons, i want to that menu be visible when i resize the browser, i  put the code in snippet,  i want the help of somebody.

this is my code

Comment: please somebody help me

Comment: i updated my code, please somebody help me to fix this code, to improve it., i uploaded the logo, please some help here, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Bootstrap v4, here for `.Logo` you have mentioned `width: 87%;` and parent as `col-md-3`. Were `md` means up to medium device, when the device below 991px, the width may come 100%. For this quick fix is apply the specific width for a logo in a media query, code given below.

```
@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .Logo {
    width: 200px !important;
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```css
body{
 padding: 13%;
}



#mimenu{
 
 padding-right: 15%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 background-color: white;
}

 a.nav-link.cuatro  {
 position: relative;
 left:-25%;
}


 a.nav-link.uno  {
 position: relative;
 left:-23%;
  text-align: center;
}

 a.nav-link.dos {
 position: relative;
 left:-53%;
  text-align: center;
}

a.nav-link.tres {
 position: relative;
 left:-20%;
 text-align: center;
}

a.nav-link.cinco {
 position: relative;
 left:-20%;
 text-align: center;
}


a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.dos{
 position: relative;
 left:-15%;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.Logo {
 
 
    width: 87%;
 position: relative;
 left:30%;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 
 
}


#uno{

padding: 0;


}


.nav-link.uno:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 
}


.nav-link.dos:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}

.nav-link.tres:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}


.nav-link.cuatro:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}

.nav-link.cinco:hover{
 
 background:  rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
}


.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
    color: white!important;
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(178,205,73,1.00)!important;
 
}

.dropdown-item{
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 width: 100%;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: rgb(0,171,235);
 
}

.dropdown-item:hover{
 
 color: rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 background: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item{
 position: relative;
 left:13%;
 

}

i.fa.fa-facebook{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-783%
  
}

i.fa.fa-facebook:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-783%
  
}



i.fa.fa-twitter{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-453%;
}

i.fa.fa-twitter:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-453%;
}




i.fa.fa-youtube{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-443%
}


i.fa.fa-youtube:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-443%
}

i.fa.fa-instagram{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-407%;
    bottom:-6%;
}

i.fa.fa-instagram:hover{
color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 
}

i.fa.fa-envelope{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-7%
}



i.fa.fa-envelope:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:-7%
}



a.info{
    color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:23%
} 




a.info:hover{
    color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 position: relative;
 left:23%
} 


a.tel{
 color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 font-family: arial;
 text-decoration:none;
}


a.tel:hover{
 color:rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
 font-family: arial;
 text-decoration:none;
}





a.info{
color:rgba(43,86,162,1.00); 
font-family: arial;
text-decoration:none; 
}



.dropdown-submenu{
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 40%;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:focus .dropdown-menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .dropdown-menu{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu{
        width: auto;
    }
}


.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 104%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: rgb(0,171,235);
 text-align-last: center; 
}

/* UPDATED CODE */
@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .Logo {
    width: 200px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-12 ">  
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="menusocial">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#" class="tel"> <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(4)7916510 ext(1501)</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="mailto:info@clinicacasadelnino.com" class="info"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@clinicacasadelnino.com</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" id="uno">
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="mimenu" >

<div class="col-3 encabezado" id="gradiente1">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/2jii6Eq.png" title="source: imgur.com" class="Logo">

</div>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mimenu2">
<li class="nav-item b ">
<a class="nav-link  dos " href="#">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item a dropdown">
<a class="nav-link uno dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Quienes Somos</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu"   aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Visión Misión y Objetivos Estrategicos</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reseña Historica</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Políticas Institucionales</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Valores</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dos" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Nuestros Servicios
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios Principales</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Urgencias</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">UCI Neonatal</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">UCI Adultos</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirugía</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hospitalización</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salas de parto</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios de apoyo</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicio de transfusión sanguínea</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Esterilización</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Imagenología</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicio farmacéutico</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nutrición</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Terapia física y respiratoria </a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ambulancia</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios de Consulta Externa</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicio de transfusión sanguínea</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pediatría</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ginecología y obstetricia</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirugía General</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirugía Pediátrica</a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item c">
<a class="nav-link tres" href="#">Responsabilidad Social</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item d">
<a class="nav-link  cuatro" href="#">Laboratorio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item d">
<a class="nav-link  cinco" href="#">Correo Corporativo</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row fila2">
<div class="col-12 imagenesc">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/GKeJMwS.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" alt="First slide"/>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block img-fluid"  alt="Second slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/CaZbz8L.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Nextborder</span> </a><!----fin carousel----->      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Codepen demo link.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/boaJJB)

Comment: you are a master satheesh kumar, thanks for help, please help me organize the navbar menu social bar.

Comment: My suggestion please have a deep look at the Bootstrap V4 documentation. I have seen some glitches in your code. My solution is only quick fix. If you want it to be clear, please have a view https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ .

Comment: If you need any other help, catch me on satheeshssk@icloud.com

Comment: can i send you the code of my page to your email, to check it out, and help me with the fixes? please?

Comment: Upload your code in github and send me the link. I will look into that on weekend.

Comment: can i send you the gmail link?

Comment: Send me the github link.

Comment: this is the link Satheesh
 https://gist.github.com/rikardoroa/93f4d77eac803d322147250c96d07cd3

Comment: have a great day, regards